PBS Pro custom stdout stderr filenames
I would like to know how to append jobID to the custom stdout file names. I don't like the default option of jobname.o and jobname.e in PBS Pro. USing SLURM, I could just define stdout filenames and append the jobID to the filenames and save them in txt formats. It works abosultely fine and make it easier to look into files from computer.
After disabling $PBS -N jobname line in the script, I tried
#Redirect the standard error file descriptor to this file.
#PBS -e err-${PBS_JOBID%%.*}.txt

#The same as above but for the standard output file descriptor
#PBS -o out-${PBS_JOBID%%.*}.txt

It does save err.txt and out.txt but doesn't append the jobID in the filenames. Any suggestions?

Try
#PBS -e err-${PBS_JOBID}.txt
#PBS -o out-${PBS_JOBID}.txt

If you only want job number part try
#PBS -e err-${PBS_JOBID%.*}.txt
#PBS -o out-${PBS_JOBID%.*}.txt


Sorry neither of this seems to work.
